# An efficient way to extract Dependency Strings from a sentence

Tags: text, natural-language

Mathematica has the built-in function TextStructure, with the option "DependencyStrings" that provides the dependency strings of a sentence. Unfortunately, this function is incredibly slow.

```
 Timing@TextStructure["He wrote a book. I read the book he wrote.", 
  "DependencyStrings", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

> ```
> {0.59375, {"(wrote, 2)((nsubj, (He, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (a, \
> 3)))))", "(read, 2)((nsubj, (I, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (the, \
> 3)), (rcmod, (wrote, 6)((nsubj, (he, 5)))))))"}}
> ```

As seen it in the example above, two sentences take 0.6 of a second. Does anyone how to speed it up or is there an alternative, as the aim is to use it on the dataset with 15,000+ observations?

Comment: Have you tried using [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/). I think it does dependency analysis. It is written in Python so easy to call from WL.

Comment: The aim is to use Wolfram language, as I am aware there are more efficient functions in Python.

Comment: I would like to use WL for everything too, but I often have to take a more pragmatic "use the right tool for the job" approach. It may be because of WL's excessive resource (CPU / Memory) requirements, missing functionality, bugs, ...

Comment: Agreed, but the requirement of my research is only to use WL, unfortunately, my hands are tied.

Comment: Which version are you using and what are your machine specs?  In version 12.0 the above returns in 0.06 seconds on my 4-year old laptop (i7 2.4GHz). If I assign to a variable and suppress the output it return s in 0.03 seconds (skips formatting for and writing result to the front-end) .

Comment: @Edmund On my Mac (2.9 GHz Intel Core i9) running V12, the above takes ~2.5s, which is a **lot** slower. Restarting Mathematica did not change the result.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi  I suggest reporting to WRI.  It seems odd to get such a performance difference between Max and Windows.  Maybe some performance improvements are coming in 12.1. WRI will be able to tell you.

Comment: Running this in version 12 on my  i7 2.8 GHz under macos takes 0.6. These timings are really inconsistent. I also think that this is a bug. Please report to support about this.

Comment: Very interesting. The result of wrapping the code with `Trace` has `LeafCount` 959186! Something must go rampage... And it seems to contain quite a lot of `JLink`- and Java-related junk.

Comment: @Edmund, I'm using a desktop i7 3.5GHz with overclocking of 4.2 and version 12.0.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, should I write to the Wolfram support about this?

Comment: Yes, definitely please. Sorry, I should have been clearer about that... =) They probably won't fix it immediately, though.

Comment: No worries, I am aware of the fact. But maybe it helps someone else in the future.